# Laying out a UITableViewCell Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm new to iOS development, I wanted to create a custom UITableViewCell. I prefer doing the layout in code rather than in IB. I created a custom cell class and added only a UIImageView for testing. I applied the following constrains:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {

    NSDictionary *views = @{
                       @"view": self.mCoverImage
                       };

    NSArray* horizontalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignmentMask metrics:nil views:views];

    NSArray* verticalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view(170)]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignmentMask metrics:nil views:views];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:horizontalConstraint];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:verticalConstraint];
}
```

but this gave me the following in the console:

```
2016-03-30 11:37:08.818 Testing3[87057:1179225] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fb033e721d0 h=--& v=--& V:[naruto(0)]   (Names: naruto:0x7fb033fb4c70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb033e6fab0 V:[naruto(170)]   (Names: naruto:0x7fb033fb4c70 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb033e6fab0 V:[naruto(170)]   (Names: naruto:0x7fb033fb4c70 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-03-30 11:37:08.819 Testing3[87057:1179225] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
```

What's wrong with my code?

**EDIT:**

Just to make it easy please find below the full source code for the delegate as well as the cell implementation:

This is the table view delegate:

```
#import "TopPointsController.h"
#import "TestCell.h"

@interface TopPointsController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mainTable;

@end

@implementation TopPointsController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mainTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.mainTable.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 50;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TestCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TestCell"];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TestCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TestCell"];
    }

    return cell;
}

@end
```

This is the cell implementation:

```
#import "TestCell.h"

@implementation TestCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.mCoverImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"naruto"];
        self.mCoverImage.image = image;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.mCoverImage];

        NSDictionary *views = @{
                                @"view": self.mCoverImage
                                };

        self.mCoverImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


        NSArray* horizontalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignmentMask metrics:nil views:views];
        NSArray* verticalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view(170)]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignmentMask metrics:nil views:views];

        [self.contentView addConstraints:horizontalConstraint];
        [self.contentView addConstraints:verticalConstraint];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: You have not turned of `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. Before adding constraints set that to false/NO

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
V:|[view(170)]|
```

Basically you are telling the view to stretch vertically on top and bottom like they are pinned to the superview, but you are also saying that the height must be 170 points.

If the cell height is bigger  or smaller than 170 points, your set of constraints can't be satisfied.
To solve that issue you can:

- Remove height constraint `V:|[view]|`
- Remove top or bottom constraint `V:[view(170)]|` or `V:|[view(170)]`
- lower one of those constraints priority, so if there is a conflict between two of them the one with the higher priority wins `V:[view(170@250)]|`

  Also pay attention to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false on the image view you added.

Do no add constraint in `layoutSubview` and always call `super.layoutSubviews()` if you are overriding it.
`layoutSubviews` can be called many times and each time is called you are adding constraints to the view. Add you constraints in `awakeFromNib`, `initWithStyle` or `updateConstraints` (but pay attention to do it once)

Comment: How to set the cell to 170? because I read that this is the way to make a dynamic cell height

Comment: Depends, there is a delegate method that asks you a height for a specific index path, or there is rowHeight property on UITableView. <br> If are using automatic cell sizing post the full code to see if there is something wrong.

Comment: I know how to do it in the delegate, but I want the cell itself to set its size. I read somewhere that the imageview should have the top,bottom,trailing,leading pinned to the content view of the cell, it should have the height as well. I tried this on IB and it worked but it didn't with code.

Comment: probably you didn't set esimatedSize to something  and rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Comment: `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is this set to false ?

Comment: @Andrea I set the estimated size to 230 and the row height to UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: @GoodSp33d yes it is set to false

Comment: Is there any other view that you are adding programmatically? pay attention that translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints should be set to no before any layout pass

Comment: @Andrea Okay I moved the code to the init method, now the cells have a small height but when clicked it expands and shows the full image

Comment: @Andrea also Xcode gives me the following warning: Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.

Comment: Without seeing the full code is impossible for to say what is happening, but I think you had a lot of clues to start dig by yourself

Comment: @Andrea please check my updates, I added the full source code.